# How to add touch event listener as a class function in Lua?

Tags: class, lua, coronasdk, addeventlistener

I am trying to add eventlistener and use it in a class function but i couldn't succeed. Could you please analyse my codes and help me out?

my fish.lua class:

```
 local class= {}

 function class.color(image)

 local color= display.newGroup();
 color=display.newImage(image)
 color:addEventListener("touch",class.listen)
 return color

end

function class.listen(event)
if(phase.event=="began") then
    print("hi")
 end
 end

return class
```

my main.lua class:

```
 local fishClass=require "fish" ;

 redfish="fish.small.red.png"
 local fish1=fishClass.color(redfish);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(phase.event=="began") then
```

Should be:

```
if(event.phase=="began") then
```